# Traverse through a list with dynamic type

Tags: asp.net, dynamic

After getting a `List<dynamic>` object from the linq query, I want to traverse through each element using the following technique. It's not working, what can be the cause?

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> lstPhysicianMeasures =
    (from pmc in y
     select new
     {
         MeasureId = pmc.PK_PRIMARY_KEY,
         Title = pmc.TITLE,
         MeasureCode = pmc.MEASURE_CODE,
         MinAge = pmc.MIN_AGE ?? 0,
         MaxAge = pmc.MAX_AGE ?? 0,
         Description = pmc.DESCRIPTION ?? string.Empty,
         IS_SELECTED = ((System.Boolean?)pmc.IS_ACTIVE ?? false)
      }).ToList();

foreach (dynamic objMeasure in lstPhysicianMeasures)
{
    var gMeasureCode = objMeasure.MeasureCode;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You have to be careful using dynamic with anonymous types, if you cross assembly boundaries it will fail due to anonymous types being internal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using var instead of dynamic.